# SQL Selecting more rows that share one column and contain one of few values in another

Tags: mysql, sql, select

let's say I have table like this:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+
| name            | playlist        |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| Jay-Z           | chill vibes     |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| Jay-Z           | rap             |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| Jay-Z           | discover weekly |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| Imagine Dragons | discover weekly |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| ZEDD            | discover weekly |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| Imagine Dragons | pop             |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I need to select an author that is in playlists DISCOVER WEEKLY and RAP. All I know are the playlists. How to do that with pure SQL, is that even possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a filter for having the number of distinct playlist equal at the number you are looking

```
  select name  
  from my_table  
  where playlist in ('discover weekly', 'rap')
  group by name
  having count(distinct playlist) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use group by and having count. see below:

```
select name
from table1
where playlist in ('rap','discover weekly')
group by name
having count(distinct playlist) = 2;

Result:  Jay-Z
```

Comment: just a but late

Comment: yup; you are the flash of SO

Comment: not   properly a flash  .. anyway your answer seems good but you should check for distinct  playlist

Comment: correct. It might have duplicate data. will update it